# payment gateways for direct transactions with banks

Tags: php, transactions, payment-gateway, bank

I am new to Payment Gateways and I am really confused in choosing the payment gateway for my website.

I have website where user have money in their online account. I need a payment gateway that can allow user to directly transfer money from their bank accounts or to their bank accounts from their online account. User can be from any region so, this payment gateway should support maximum no. of international banks.

Also the payment gateway should be compatible with PHP.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really a programming question, should be on the webmasters SO.

Comment: I know its not really a programming question, but since I am regular user of stackoverflow and there is a lot experienced people here , so I thought to put this question here also.

Comment: @Sumit did you ever find such a solution?

Comment: @socca1157: To be honest now I don't even remember it. I think by seeing that I marked Matt's answer correct, so this might be the solution. But as I said, I am not sure. Sorry couldnt help you on this.

Comment: Oh ok thanks @Sumit, doesn't look like Envoy supports any American Institutes unfortunately. Hate how outdated the industry is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like [Envoy Services](http://www.envoyservices.com/en_services.php?pageSelect=eocs&page=services), perhaps?  They offer a number of services, including a hosted gateway which can be used to gather a user's bank account details (the structure of which can vary depending on the user's region), and APIs to manage payments to and from those accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at PayPal? They have a PHP API and they support bank accounts.

Comment: The thing is by using Paypal , user will need to have paypal account, and then user will transfer money to his/her paypal account and then to bank account, I need payment gateway through which user can directly transfer is money to bank account from my website...please correct me If I am wrong in Paypal understanding

Comment: With PayPal, a user can pay you with a debit card (or credit card) without a PayPal account. It uses a guest account. But I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. With the PayPal Pro version ($30 per month) you can use an API that does not require the user to interact with the PayPal web site. Everything is taken care of behind the scene between your server and PayPal.

Comment: I dont want an API that can allow user to pay me, I want a API that can allow user to withdraw their money to their banks directly and vice a versa (i.e. an API that can allow user to withdraw money from bank directly and put them in account on my website.)

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking for payment gateways.
Here is my study on payment gateways. Now a days you will get payment gateway API for maximum programming platforms. If you are using PHP then options are unlimited. You can also ask to payment gateway providers to provide you "How to Guide" for integration of their gateways. 
Many things you have to keep in mind before choosing payment gateways. Some of are as below:

1. What type of transactions do you need. Credit cards, Debit card, Net Banking, Cash cards etc.
2. What is the Setup fees which is varies from Rs. 0 to Rs. 30,000.
3. What is the Annual Maintenance Charges (AMC) are going to cost you for using their gateway for long time.
4. Most important what will be the TDR (Transaction Discount Rate) by gateways. Suppose customer pay online for Rs. 100, what will you get after deducting TDR. For example on use of credit card and netbanking TDR rate may be higher in comparision to Debit cards. It may be differ to different payment gateway providers. Now a days usually for Debit cards it is 1.25% to 1.5%, Credit Cards 2% to 3.75%, Net Banking 2% to 4% depends on plans you chose.
5. Payout Time : Whan will the amount reflects in your account on successful transaction.
6. Customer Suport.
7. Refund Management
8. Data Analytics, transaction reports
9. Merchant interface to keep a track of all your transactions on real time basis
10. Security of Transactions

Hope this helps you.